# What is the correct If P, then Q translation of In order for A, there must be B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Not sure how to do this translation. For example:

1) In order for you to succeed, you must be determined.

I think this would translate to

1') If you are not determined, then you will not succeed.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.

In general, if $P$ is a *necessary* condition for $Q$, then we have that $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$ which by contraposition is equivalent to $Q \rightarrow P$ ... which is just the reverse from $P \rightarrow Q$, which is what we get if $P$ is a *sufficient* condition for $Q$.

When it says that something $P$ has to be true "in order for" $Q$ to be true, then that is saying that $P$ is a necessary condition for $Q$.

In this case, we are told that you must be determined in order to succceed, and so being determined is a necessary condition for succeeding, meaning indeed that if we are not determined, we won't succeed.